# URL Based Localization in .NET core Razor - how to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-localization, iso-3166

I am building a .NET 8.0 Razor Page site where localization/internationalization is made with URLs like:

```
example.org/us // United States
example.org/fr // France
example.org/pt // Portugal
example.org/se // Sweden
...

example.org/us/contact  // contact page for USA (text is displayed in English)
example.org/fr/contact  // contact page for France (text is displayed in French)
```

i.e. URLs contain [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) codes for countries (e.g. us, fr, pt, se etc). Text is coming from standard Resource files (resx).

Most of my implementation works but I have slight problem where *non-existing* pages return a `StatusCode 200` instead of `404`. I have Googled, looked at other examples but they are either dated/no longer working, or only work for MVC. This question is for Razor Pages using  `@page "/..."` directive.

I need help and inputs on the implementation.

All my Razor Pages have `{lang}` in their page route. The Contact page route will be `/{lang}/contact`. `{lang}` refers to the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code.

The following code prepends the `{lang}`-parameter to all pages in the web application:

```
public class CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention: IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;

            if (template.StartsWith("MicrosoftIdentity")) continue;  // Skip MicrosoftIdentity pages

            // Prepend {lang}/ to the page routes allow for route-based localization
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Order = -1;
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{lang}", template);
        }
    }
}
```

...instantiated in `program.cs` with:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // decorate all page routes with {lang} e.g. @page "/{lang}..."
    options.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention());
});
```

To set the actual Culture for the page requested, I have implemented a custom `RequestCultureProvider` with the following:

```
public class CustomRouteDataRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public SupportedAppLanguages SupportedAppLanguages;
    public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {

        var lang = (string)httpContext.GetRouteValue("lang");
        var urlCulture = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/')[1];

        string[] container = [lang, urlCulture];
        
        var culture = SupportedAppLanguages.Dict.Values.SingleOrDefault(langInApp => container.Contains(langInApp.Icc) );

        if (culture != null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(culture.Culture));
        }

        // if no match, return 404
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
        return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(Options.DefaultRequestCulture.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName));
    }
}
```

...instantiated via `program.cs`:

```
// get all languages supported by app via `appsettings.json`:
var supportedAppLanguages = builder.Configuration.GetSection("SupportedAppLanguages").Get<SupportedAppLanguages>();
var supportedCultures = supportedAppLanguages.Dict.Values.Select(langInApp => new CultureInfo(langInApp.Culture)).ToList();

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-us", uiCulture: "en-us");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.FallBackToParentCultures = true;

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRouteDataRequestCultureProvider() { Options = options, SupportedAppLanguages = supportedAppLanguages });
});
```

To prevent users from entering weird locale/country codes (and confusing search engines/preventing bad SEO), I created a MiddlewareFilter to deal with such cases:

```
public class RouteConstraintMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, SupportedAppLanguages supportedAppLanguages) 
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        // The context.Response.StatusCode for pages like example.org/us/non-existing is 200 and not the correct 404.
        // How can I implement a proper check?
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound) return; 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context?.GetRouteValue("lang")?.ToString())) return;

        // check for a match 
        var lang = context.GetRouteValue("lang").ToString();
        var supported = supportedAppLanguages.Dict.Values.Any(langInApp => lang == langInApp.Icc);
       
        if (!supported)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            return;
        }

        await next(context);
    }
}
```

The current state of the app:

```
example.org/us       // 200. (correct)
example.org/fr       // 200. (correct)
example.org/nonsense/contact // 404. (correct)
example.org/nonsense         // 404. (correct)
example.org/us/non-existing  // 200. (wrong, must return 404)
```

How can I fix this? Is this a good implementation as well (seems kind of clunky to me)?
Can it be solved in a better way? A simplified Github repro is available here: https://github.com/shapeh/TestLocalization

Hoping for some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by your `RouteConstraintMiddleware`

this line would shortcut your middleware pineline

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context?.GetRouteValue("lang")?.ToString())) return;
```

without `await next(context);` it won't get into next middleware,the codes that  return 404 response won't be executed

In my opinion,you may try add a [RouteConstraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-route-constraints) to your `{lang}` section,the default Route middleware would handle it for you,so that you don't need to add another middleware

A minimal example:

```
public class CultureConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
   
    public bool Match(
        HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, string routeKey,
        RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var routeValue))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var supportedAppLanguages = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IConfiguration>().GetSection("SupportedAppLanguages").Get<SupportedAppLanguages>();
        


        var routeValueString = Convert.ToString(routeValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        

        return supportedAppLanguages.Dict.Values.Select(x=>x.Icc).Contains(routeValueString);
    }
}
```

Register the constraint:

```
builder.Services.AddRouting(options =>
{
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
    options.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("cultureconstraint", typeof(CultureConstraint));
});
```

Remove  the middleware:

```
app.UseMiddleware<RouteConstraintMiddleware>(supportedAppLanguages);
```

modify `CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention`:

```
public class CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention: IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;

            if (template.StartsWith("MicrosoftIdentity")) continue;  // Skip MicrosoftIdentity pages

            // Prepend {lang}/ to the page routes allow for route-based localization
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Order = -1;
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{lang:cultureconstraint}", template);
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. One can only wonder why Microsoft does not have any good examples on doing this. Thanks.